# Buscar datos que contienen caracteres especiales en SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Requiero realizar la siguiente consulta usando SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM PedidosSeriales
WHERE serial = 181115'00136
```

Pero me arroja el siguiente error:

> Mens. 105, Nivel 15, Estado 1, Línea 2
>       Falta la comilla de cierre después de la cadena de caracteres '00136
>       '.

¿Qué instrucción puedo indicarle para poder consultar de esta manera?

Ahora:
supongamos que tenemos ese dato en una variable y queremos consultarlo

```
declare @serie varchar(max) = 181114'01997
select * from PedidosSeriales
where serial = @serie
```

de entrada esta query falla obviamente, lo que quiero dar a entender es como escapo el dato en caso de que lo obtenga de esta forma

Comment: que gestor de bases de datos estás usando?

Comment: sql server 2012

Comment: ¿Cuál es el serial que desas consultar? Veo que el que pones lleva una comilla simple `81115'00136`, ¿ese es el número que requieres?

Comment: hola phi, el dato es ese. El dato que requiero consultar contiene ese caracter en el medio

Comment: Entonces por lo que veo, el campo `serial` es un `VARCHAR`, y para consultarlo debe ir entre comillas simples, pero como en tu caso lleva una comilla el dato, tendrás que escaparlo de la siguiente manera `... WHERE serial = '81115''00136'`

Comment: perfecto me ha funcionado. Tengo una duda de mas, cuando este dato esta en una variable como lo escapo?

Comment: ¿Tienes un ejemplo de cómo podría llegar esa información desde una variable? Para poder darte una solución más integral. Si gustas ponerlo como una pregunta nueva sería mucho mejor ;)

Comment: acabo de editar la pregunta para hacerme entender un poco sobre lo que pretendo

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88113/discussion-between-phi-and-andrex-11).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes escapar la apostrofe si la escribes dos veces:

`SELECT * FROM PedidosSeriales WHERE serial = '181115''00136'`

o puedes agregarla concatenandola con su valor `char()`:

`SELECT * FROM PedidosSeriales WHERE serial = '181115'+ char(39) +'00136'`